# Face Appearing that can't be selected

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, faces

I'm encountering an issue in Blender 2.79b where a face has appeared in my mesh that doesn't seem to be a face.  I say this because in edit mode with face selection enabled (see screenshot) the face can't be selected.  Vertices and edges for this face also can't be selected when in the appropriate selection modes.  When you attempt to select the face the selection actually goes right through the mesh and selects a face on the backside of the model.  My problem is that I want to remove whatever this is so I can replace it with a real face; if I try to apply a subsurface modifier to the model right now this pseudo-face merges with the face next to it and messes up the mesh.  Any help understanding what this is and how I remove it is greatly appreciated; thanks!

P.S. - If it helps in resolving the issue, this "face" appeared after clicking "Apply" on a mirror modifier I was working with.  It showed up on the half of the model that was being "mirrored".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's just a face in another object?

Maybe provide your .blend so we can investigate quicker.

Comment: Ugh! Yes, this is exactly it (the face is part of a separate object).  The solution was to hide all objects in the scene then make them visible one at a time to see which faces were associated with each one.  I had to separate part of my mesh into a different object yesterday to limit what the subsurface modifier was applying to and it looks like I got an extra face selected that I didn't intend to.  I couldn't select the face in edit mode because it belongs to another object now.  Anyways, thanks for the mental prompt to check this.

Comment: Pro tip : name your objects so you never wonder what they are. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be another object. Hitting / on the numpad in edit mode will toggle showing only the current object being edited. Keep in mind that the local view mode (usually called solo in other software) may change the view orientation and 3D cursor position.